# Redux Update a state with an array of objects

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a state like this:

```
this.state ={
  photos: [
    { description: 'someDescription', id: 1 },
    { description: 'someDescription', id: 2 },
    { description: 'someDescription', id: 3 }
  ]
}
```

How can I update one of the descriptions only?
Or I have to do something like

```
this.setState({ photos: newArrayOfObjectsWithOnlyOneUpdatedDescription })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a funtion to do it for you like this:

```
const updatePhoto = (id, desc) => 
    this.state.photos.map((obj) => 
    obj.id === id ? Object.assign(obj, { description: desc }) : obj)
```

`map` function will return a new array, so you won't need to do a manual state cloning stuff.

Then reuse it as you need it:

```
this.setState({ photos: updatePhoto(2, 'new desc') })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create copy of state, then update copied state and setState

```
let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state); // get the current state copy
stateCopy.photos = stateCopy.photos.slice(); // get photos object
stateCopy.photos[key] = Object.assign({}, stateCopy.photos[key]); 
stateCopy.photos[key].description = 'new decription'; // update description of specific key
this.setState(stateCopy); // set state
```